Charging a Battery Energy Storage System (BESS: 600MW/ 1200MWh) with a Higher rated Power Plant (1200MW)
A project mentions requirement of setting up a 1200MW solar power plant with atleast 600MW/1200MWh BESS system. The BESS is to be charged exclusively with solar power. My confusion is what if the solar power is producing power at its peak ie 1200MW, wont it damage the BESS while charging? Am I missing any crucial component in between which can make this happen without any loss of power?
Please help me with this basic question.

Why not start with a single 12v panel and a small battery?

how will that help? the fundamental question still remains

Because you will have less damage when you mess it up.

one assumes the plant would supply loads during the day while charging the battery for use at night.  There isn't much point of a system whose sole use is to charge batteries.  But every electrical supply system must be regulated, you cant just throw megawatts of power onto the grid with an expectation it will be consumed.

Actually the wording in Project is misleading. 1200MW is not the output of Solar PV plant. Solar output has to be designed in accordance with the BESS ie 600MW
